# Python problemas com Lista muito grande

Tags: python-3.x

Estou fazendo um script Python e estou recebendo uma msg
de erro que não consigo resolver

x = [int(e) for e in input().split()]

msg de erro:
MemoryError
Command exited with non-zero status (1)

tentei usar o map:

x = list(map(int, input().split()))

msg de erro:
MemoryError
Command exited with non-zero status (1)

Geralmente as entradas não excedem 10.000 numeros
e o computador tem 32Gb de RAM? O que posso fazer, o SO é de 64Bits?

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir. O erro acontece quando você faz `entrada = input()` e cola o resultado? Suspeito que tenha a ver com o buffer de entrada, e não com a conversão pra `int`.

Comment: Quando coloco mais de 10000 entradas no input, acontece o erro! Vi na documentação que a lista tem uma limitação de entradas em 12000 elementos, tentei  criar um txt com o gravando o arquivo, mas não consigo usar os dados como listas da mesma forma.

Comment: @weltonvaz input() com mais de 10 mil elementos não tem sentido, são dados de entrada via teclado até onde eu me lembre, é insano para um usuário digitar essa quantidade de elementos não é não ?

Answer (score -2):

Meu caro, seu script não esta errado, eu mesmo o testei no meu compilador e o aceitou de maneira correta, algo deve estar acontecendo com seu compilador ou coisa relacionada, visto que eu acabei de testar e não deu nenhum erro, caso queira mandar imagens poderia ficar mais fácil de lhe ajudar.

Comment: O Python tem uma limitação no numero de elementos de uma lista, este é o problema. Como sou novato, não consegui fazer ele gravar o input num txt e depois recuperar a linha com o dados(um inteiro qualquer). Ele sempre tem que ler o txt completo para acessar a linha que preciso, isso é demorado e custoso

Comment: Exato, ele tem que fazer isto toda vez porque ele não tem capacidade de ir apenas no local e pegar o inteiro, um grande problema e que nesse caso acarreta o erro, infelizmente não tem como concertar isso.

Comment: Obrigado Eron! Eu já tentei criar um arquivo na memoria com "import tempfile", mas ele não grava listas.

Comment: Dboas cara, a computação é limitada, nada podemos fazer, só seguir